# Angular 2 unit tests: How to override @Inject('Window') private _window: Window constructor dependency?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I tried the following, for example:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [CmpBeingTested],
        providers: [ 
            {provide: window, useValue: window}

        ]
    });
}));
```

I am not able to override CmpBeingTested constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject('Window') private _window: Window) { }
```

And I keep getting the error

No provider for Window!

Answer (score 0):

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {

        let windowMock: Window = { } as any;

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [CmpBeingTested],
            providers: [ 
                { provide: 'Window', useFactory: (() => { return  windowMock; }) }

            ]
        });
    }));
```